# What is the difference between the Master branch of ROS2 and the dashing or eloquent branch?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From reading the Navigation2 tutorial, it is specified that in order to write a new plugin for Navigation2, the source build should be done using the master branch ros2.repos file, and that Navigation2 and its dependencies should also be built from the master branch.

[navigation2 tutotial : writing new costmap2d plugin](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/writing_new_costmap2d_plugin.html)

[navigation2 tutotial : writing new nav2planner plugin](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/writing_new_nav2planner_plugin.html)

Is it possible to make a plugin written in this environment work with ROS2 (or binary) and Navigation2 built from a branch of dashing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353945/what-is-the-difference-between-the-master-branch-of-ros2-and-the-dashing-or-eloquent-branch?/) by [fuji](https://answers.ros.org/users/55387/fuji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can of course write a custom plugin based on the operating system and version of navigation2 you use for your work. However, that's not the recommended developer workflow because you're then not getting access to potentially the most recent capabilities. If you want to integrate them upstream, some effort will need to be taken to migrate it over to master. Dashing is pretty old by ROS2 standards and I think you'll find that the state of dashing vs master its worth being on master, or at least Eloquent.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fuji](https://answers.ros.org/users/55387/fuji/) on 2020-06-08**:
Thank you very much for your response.I understood the difference of the branches.